# What is OLicenseHeartbeat.exe and how can I prevent it from running?

Tags: windows, office365

A few days ago, Windows started running the process OLicenseHeartbeat.exe (Office Subscription Licensing Heartbeat) every day at a certain time.

I'm not sure what it does. And the worse thing is it's killing the CPU. It consumes so much that the CPU Reaches 100% utilization.

What does this process do? Is there a way to stop it from running?

Comment: This task really should be using that many resources though, how much of the CPU do you actually see it using in task manager?

Comment: Pure speculation: It’s supposed to tell Microsoft an installation is still active and in use. They could then possibly mark not-in-use installations in the Office 365 Control Panel to make revocation easier.

Comment: I suppose the high CPU usage could be do to an anti virus scan as well. Do you happen to see anything in the windows event viewer during the time of the slow down?

Answer (score 3):

It's a scheduled task that is set up during Office install. There is a service that the task manually executes at certain times.

If you go to the Task Scheduler you should be able to find it and disable it (or go to `services.msc` and disable the service it executes), although I'm unsure of what side effects maybe encountered.

Comment: Questions that require answers from the author should be contained within comments, and those comments should be deleted, once you receive enough information to answer the question.  *Most questions contained within answers are not answered.*  When I see a question contained within an answer, its a huge red flag, when it comes  to the quality of the answer.

Comment: I found the statement that this task checks for the subscription licence in the depths of the internet. However, does anybody know what happens if you disable it?